# Resolving enum34 metaclass conflict?

Tags: python, enums, metaclass

Is there any way to get a custom metaclass to play nice with the enum34 package (pre Python 3)?

```
import enum
import six

class MyMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, class_name, bases, class_dict):
        print("Does something useful.")
        return super(MyMeta, cls).__new__(cls, class_name, bases, class_dict)

@six.add_metaclass(MyMeta)
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

MyEnum = enum.Enum('MyEnum', [('One', 1), ('Two', 2), ('Three', 3)], type=MyClass)
```

The above currently raises an error in enum34 at `enum_class = super(EnumMeta, metacls).__new__(metacls, cls, bases, classdict)`:

```
TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why do you need a mixin?

Comment: Well, essentially I was hoping to create an enum whose values are derived from a custom type. Unfortunately, the type in question has a metaclass, which is where the trouble starts. I guess I'll just have to put my values in a dictionary or something.

Comment: You could derive `MyMeta` from both metaclasses, but I personally don't like new enums and would avoid them.

Comment: Like I said, as soon as I derive `MyMeta` from `enum.EnumMeta`, I get another error. I guess that `enum.EnumMeta.__new__` looks for `enum.Enum` among the base classes. Not sure how to fix that though, it's all getting pretty convoluted.

Comment: I wrote you in my comment how to fix this.

Comment: This looks like an interesting problem.  ;)  Can you give a cut-down version of the custom values you are trying to use?

Comment: @EthanFurman The custom values were instances of a class with traits (along the lines of http://code.enthought.com/projects/traits/), hence the need for the metaclass. I have since switched to a simple dictionary key/value mapping instead of an enum to avoid such problems.

Answer (score 1):

You should derive `MyMeta` from `enum.Enum`'s metaclass:

```
class MyMeta(type(enum.Enum)):
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that does not work. Instead, you then get the following error: `TypeError: new enumerations must be created as 'ClassName([mixin_type,] enum_type)'`.

Comment: I guess that's the limitation of Enum34 for Python 2. According to the docs, the `type` argument for `Enum`  is "type to mix in to new Enum class." If you need a mixin, do (as the message suggests): `class MyEnum(MyClass, enum.Enum):`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of enum.Enum. you should write only Enum. That problem will solved.

For ex:

```
        class MyEnumClass(Enum):
               ........
```